# Not able to scrape h3 tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

The url in question is:
http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=machine%20learning

I want to the extract the links to all the matching results in the first page and I believe the corresponding html is:

```
<h3 class="newaps">
    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1600490069" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
    <span class="lrg bold"> … </span>
    </a>
    <span class="med reg"> … </span>
</h3>
```

This is what I have tried so far without any luck:

```
In [39]: url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=machine%20learning"

In [40]: page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

In [42]: html = page.read()

In [44]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [45]: soup.findAll('h3',{'class': 'newaps'})
Out[45]: []
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of beautifulsoup are you using?

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup